# How to launch jython console from maven

Tags: maven, jython

This looks like exactly what I would like:

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Yoshiori/20081125/1227615261

(in Japanese, but should be apparent what it does from the commands and output)

Unfortunately, when I try those steps, it seems the plugin no longer exists at that location.  Googling for it elsewhere also failed.

In short, what I'd like is to launch a jython shell with all of the pom file dependencies available on the Jython class path (hope I got that terminology right).  I have a project with a rather complex and changing set of dependencies defined in maven.  If I can just launch Jython from the same pom file, then I can experiment with and script all of those classes.

Other suggestions for easily loading maven dependencies into a jython shell?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [maven-jython-compile-plugin](http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/compile/). This plugin allows you to deploy a standalone project that includes jython with libraries. There is a [demo project](http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/compile/demo/) that shows how to use this plugin. Specifically, look at AbstractInitJython and InitJython in the [code repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/mavenjython/code/ci/HEAD/tree/jython-compile-maven-plugin-test/src/main/java/net/sf/mavenjython/) on how to launch a python/jython console. It will have all the libraries of the project, all pom dependencies and all the python libraries requested.

The sourceforge umbrella project is http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/